# How to change color between two different columns in a scatterplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have the following code:

```
plt.scatter(moving_avg_temp.chicagoMA, moving_avg_temp.globalMA)
plt.title('Correlation between Chicago & Global 5 Year MA')
plt.xlabel('Chicago 5 Year MA')
plt.ylabel('Global 5 Year MA')
plt.show()
```

Which results in a scatterplot where every data point is the same color. I am trying to have moving_avg_temp.chicagoMA be a different color than moving_avg_temp.globalMA to visualize the correlation between the two variables.

I am using pandas and Matplotlib.pyplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a code snippet that might help you:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


x = [1,2,3,4,7,8,7]
y = [4,1,3,6,3,6,8]

plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')

x2 = [5,6,7,8]
y2 = [1,3,5,2]

plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='lightblue')

plt.title('Correlation between Chicago & Global 5 Year MA')
plt.xlabel('Chicago 5 Year MA')
plt.ylabel('Global 5 Year MA')

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here is a list with all the color names within MatplotLib --> https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html